# Align checkboxes to the left

Tags: css

I have styled my checkboxes and for some reason I cannot get the boxes top float on the left side of the text. I have tried floats inlines blocks nothing seems to work. I was able to float the text to the right but it put a big gap between the box and text

```css
.regular-checkbox {
 display: none;
}

.regular-checkbox + label {
 background-color: #f0f0ee;
 border: 1px solid #dcdcda;
 box-shadow: none;
 padding: 9px;
 border-radius: 0px;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
}

.regular-checkbox + label:active, .regular-checkbox:checked + label:active {
 box-shadow: none; 
}

.regular-checkbox:checked + label {
 background-color: #f0f0ee;
 border: 1px solid #dcdcda;
 box-shadow: none;
 color: #99a1a7;
}

.regular-checkbox:checked + label:after {
 content: '\2714';
 font-size: 15px;
 position: absolute;
 top: -4px;
 left: 3px;
 color: #99a1a7;
}


.tag {
 position: relative;
 top: 0px;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #000;
}
```

```html
    <div class="large-12 columns">
  <div>
   <div class="tag">Box 1</div>
   <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1-1" class="regular-checkbox"><label for="checkbox-1-1"></label>
  </div>
  <div>
   <div class="tag">Box 2</div>
   <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-2-1" class="regular-checkbox"><label for="checkbox-2-1"></label>
  </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you could change your `html markup` i.e adding `.tag` after `checkbox, label` and solve that easily or make use of `css left` property to align `check-box` before `text`.

HTML changes could be as such,

```css
.regular-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.regular-checkbox + label {
  background-color: #f0f0ee;
  border: 1px solid #dcdcda;
  box-shadow: none;
  padding: 9px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.regular-checkbox + label:active,
.regular-checkbox:checked + label:active {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.regular-checkbox:checked + label {
  background-color: #f0f0ee;
  border: 1px solid #dcdcda;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: #99a1a7;
}

.regular-checkbox:checked + label:after {
  content: '\2714';
  font-size: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  left: 3px;
  color: #99a1a7;
}

.tag {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #000;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="large-12 columns">
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1-1" class="regular-checkbox">
    <label for="checkbox-1-1"></label>
       <div class="tag">Box 1</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-2-1" class="regular-checkbox">
    <label for="checkbox-2-1"></label>
    <div class="tag">Box 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This using `CSS left` property.

```css
.regular-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.regular-checkbox + label {
  background-color: #f0f0ee;
  border: 1px solid #dcdcda;
  box-shadow: none;
  padding: 9px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: -30px;
}

.regular-checkbox + label:active,
.regular-checkbox:checked + label:active {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.regular-checkbox:checked + label {
  background-color: #f0f0ee;
  border: 1px solid #dcdcda;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: #99a1a7;
}

.regular-checkbox:checked + label:after {
  content: '\2714';
  font-size: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  left: 3px;
  color: #99a1a7;
}

.tag {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #000;
  left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="large-12 columns">
  <div>
    <div class="tag">Box 1</div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1-1" class="regular-checkbox">
    <label for="checkbox-1-1"></label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="tag">Box 2</div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-2-1" class="regular-checkbox">
    <label for="checkbox-2-1"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```